# Code for setting IntProperty with just even numbers

Tags: user-interface, properties, blender

I hope somebody can help me. I want to have a IntProperty in Blender where I can set only even numbers (0,2,4,6..)

I know that the Syntax for the Float Property is the following:

```
bpy.types.Scene.MyFloat = FloatProperty(
        name='FLoat',
        default=1,
        min=0,
        step=200,
        )
```

But with this code in the GUI I can still choose e.g. "4.2" as a value so that isn't a appropriate solution to my problem.

The Syntax for the IntProperty in this way would be like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.MyInt = IntProperty(
    name='Int',
    default=1,
    min=0,
    step=2,
    )
```

doesn't work.

Does anyone knows if there is a code for choosing only even numbers and how it is?

Comment: For Blender 2.81 it seems there is an extra `,` in your `IntProperty`, i.e. `bpy.types.Scene.MyInt = IntProperty(
    name='Int',
    default=1,
    min=0,
    step=2
    )`

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I have found a solution for my problem.

Just use the Floatproperty with a stepsize of 200 and define a update function which then checks if the adjusted value is even - if not you force the conversion to the next near even number. The code then looks like that:

```
 bpy.types.Scene.even_number= FloatProperty(
    name='Even Numbers',
    description='Just even numbers are possible',
    default = 10,
    min = 0,
    max = 90,
    step = 200,
    update = update_even_numbers
    )

def update_even_numbers(scene, context):   
    if bpy.context.scene.framestep % 2 == 0: 
          print('Even number')
    else:
          x = bpy.context.scene.even_number
          bpy.context.scene.even_number= round(x/2)*2
```

Maybe if somebody else is looking for a solution this one will help him